# Code to generate unique ID with the prefix

Tags: vba, excel

Kindly help me in generating a unique ID with a prefix. I am developing a small project in Excel for storing customers database. I have a UserForm with the text fields in it. I want a code which will generate a unique ID each time when I add a new customer profile with a prefix, say `CTR`.

Comment: Please provide the sourcecode you tried so far. Imo you should switch to Access if you want to handle this with MS-Office. If it's a larger database set up a relational database system (Oracle, MSSQL, etc.)

Comment: @psychicebola Access IS a relational database program. The others you list are servers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways.  Say you store your customer names in column **A** of some sheet starting in cell **A2**.  Each time you add a customer, add their name to the column **A** list.  To assign a unique customer ID, in cell **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2="","","CTR" & ROW()-1)
```

and copy down:

[image]

If you want code to make the new ID, then:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim LastId As String, NewId As String
   Dim N As Long

   N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
   LastId = Cells(N, "B").Value
   NewId = "CTW" & CLng(Mid(LastId, 4)) + 1
   MsgBox NewId
End Sub
```

[image]